# database design for tree structure with just one level

Tags: database-design, schema

is it possible to design a database with a classic tree structure (no nested-set), forcing to have just 2 levels?

the table I thought should be:

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | NULL |
| 2 | child | 1 |
| 3 | grand_child **ERROR** | 2 |

The third row shouldn't be possible.
Can I get that without trigger or without any programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is making the parent node into separate table with the same set of fields*. Then no nested references would be possible.

For example, you could have following entities (SQL-like pseudocode)

```
CREATE TABLE RootNode
(
    Id INT,
    ...other fields as needed...
);


CREATE TABLE ChildNode
(
    Id INT,
    Parent_FK INT REFERENCES RootNode (Id), 
    ...other fields as needed (same as in RootNode)...
);
```

*I actually suspect the parent table and child table might get different fields over time, but that depends on what you are actually trying to model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you be more specific please? With an example?

Comment: What about the columns are exactly the same between parent and child?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Yano_of_queenscastles just to provide a sample:

```
INSERT INTO RootNode (Id, OtherField1, OtherField2)
VALUES
    (1, 'Root 1 Data', 'More data for Root 1'),
    (2, 'Root 2 Data', 'More data for Root 2');

-- Sample data for ChildNode table
INSERT INTO ChildNode (Id, Parent_FK, ChildField1, ChildField2)
VALUES
    (101, 1, 'Child 1 Data', 'More data for Child 1'),
    (102, 1, 'Child 2 Data', 'More data for Child 2'),
    (103, 2, 'Child 3 Data', 'More data for Child 3');
```